# How to make a fill an image with white whilst keeping transparent pixels in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, image-processing

I played around with the ColorFilter.matrix, greying the child. But what I want is a pure white replacement for any non transparent pixel.

Any idea?

```dart
 final greyedMatrix = ColorFilter.matrix(<double>[
    0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0, 
    0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0, 
    0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
  ]);
  Widget white(BuildContext context) {
    return ColorFiltered(
      colorFilter: greyedMatrix,
      child:
          Text(icon,
              style: Theme.of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .headline1!
                  .apply(fontSizeFactor: 2.3)),
     
    );
```